# Proof Verification: Prove $f(n)<2$, when $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1) = \sqrt{(2+f(n))}$ for all $n$ positive integers

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Proceed by induction:
Suppose $P(n)$ is the statement $f(n)<2$, when $n$ $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1) = \sqrt{(2+f(n))}$ for all $n$ positive integers.

Base case: $P(1)=f(1)=1<2$. True.

Assume $P(n)$, i.e. $f(n)<2$ when $n$ $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1) = \sqrt{(2+f(n))}$ for all $n$ positive integers, is true.Then $P(n+1)=\sqrt{(2+f(n))}< \sqrt{(2+2)}=2$. QED

If this is a correct proof, can you please explain how the step:$P(n+1)=\sqrt{(2+f(n))}<\sqrt{(2+2)}=2$ works. Namely, how can we substitute $f(n)$ with $2$.

Thank you!

Comment: Please try posting clearly with formulae written in mathjax. This is near impossible to read.

Comment: You may also notice that $f(n)=2\cos\theta_n$ for some $\theta_n\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ implies 
$$ f(n+1)=\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta_n} = 2\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}$$
hence by induction $f(n) = 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}\right)$ and this sequence is trivially increasing towards $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is confusing
because you use "="
as both ordinary equality
and specifying a proposition.

I will use ":" for the latter.

We then have
$P(n): f(n) < 2$.

Then,
if $P(n)$ is true,
we want to show 
$P(n+1): f(n+1) < 2$.

But

$\begin{array}\\
f(n+1) 
&= \sqrt{f(n)+2}
\qquad\text{definition of }f(n)\\
&\lt \sqrt{2+2}
\qquad\text{induction hypothesis}\\
&=\sqrt{4}\\
&=2\\
\end{array}
$

so
$P(n+1)$ is true.

Comment: Yeah I can see why, I usually say P(n): . Thanks for letting me know. Your inductive steps are the same as mine, so that is a clarification. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:  obviously $f(n) \ge 0$ for all $\,n\,$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n+1) = \sqrt{f(n)+2} \quad&\iff\quad \left(f(n+1)\right)^2 = f(n)+2 \\
 &\iff\quad \left(f(n+1)\right)^2 -4 = f(n) - 2 \\
 &\iff\quad \big(f(n+1)-2\big)\underbrace{\big(f(n+1)+2\big)}_{\gt 0}=f(n)-2
\end{align}
$$

It follows that all differences $f(n)-2$ have the same sign, and since $f(1) \lt 2$ they are all negative.